# IP fragmentation Number Of Fragments

Tags: c#, .net, packet

I am using `PcapDotNet` DLLS to play Pcap file and add the option to split packet (fragmentation):

```
    private IEnumerable<Packet> SplitPacket(Packet packet, int numberOfFragments)
    {
        IpV4Datagram ipV4Datagram = packet.Ethernet.IpV4;

        if (ipV4Datagram.Protocol == IpV4Protocol.Tcp || ipV4Datagram.Protocol == IpV4Protocol.Udp)
        {
            EthernetLayer ethernet = (EthernetLayer)packet.Ethernet.ExtractLayer();
            ILayer layer = packet.Ethernet.IpV4.ExtractLayer();
            TcpLayer tcpLayer = (TcpLayer)packet.Ethernet.IpV4.Tcp.ExtractLayer();
            tcpLayer.Checksum = null;
            IpV4Layer ipV4Layer = (IpV4Layer)packet.Ethernet.IpV4.ExtractLayer();
            ipV4Layer.HeaderChecksum = null;
            DateTime packetTimestamp = packet.Timestamp;
            PayloadLayer payload = (PayloadLayer)packet.Ethernet.IpV4.Payload.ExtractLayer(); //extract the data
            int totalLength = payload.Length;

            int partialLength = totalLength / numberOfFragments; //split data into smaller segments
            if (partialLength == 0)
                partialLength = 8;

            partialLength = (partialLength / 8) * 8; //make sure it's divisible with 8
            //(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Fragmentation_and_reassembly)
            ushort offset = 0; //send one by one

            while (offset < totalLength)
            {
                int fragmentLength = partialLength; //get length for this fragment
                IpV4FragmentationOptions options = IpV4FragmentationOptions.MoreFragments;

                if (offset + fragmentLength >= totalLength) //is this the last fragment ? trim length if needed
                {
                    options = IpV4FragmentationOptions.None;
                    fragmentLength = totalLength - offset;
                }

                byte[] newBuffer = ipV4Datagram.Payload.ToArray(); //copy the actual data into a new buffer
                PayloadLayer newPayload = new PayloadLayer { Data = new Datagram(newBuffer, offset, fragmentLength) };
                ipV4Layer.Fragmentation = new IpV4Fragmentation(options, offset); //change IP layer fragmentation options
                yield return PacketBuilder.Build(packetTimestamp, ethernet, ipV4Layer, tcpLayer, newPayload); //return
                offset += (ushort)fragmentLength; //next offset
            }
        }
    }
```

I am calling the function this way: `SplitPacket(Packet, 2);`

When take `Pcap` file with 200 packet and call the function with `numberOfFragments = 2` received ~330 packets
When call the function with `numberOfFragments = 3`: received ~600 packets
When call the function with `numberOfFragments = 4`: received more than 100,000 packets
What does this value mean and why this strange behavior ?

Comment: You allow partialLength to be 0, not a good idea.

Comment: Can you elaborate please ?

Comment: Use totalLength = 31 and numberOfFragments = 4 and your code gets  stuck in an endless loop.

Comment: Is it possible that this case happen to me, after numberOfFragments = 4 Wireshark didn't stop to received packets and after more tan 100,000 i stop it, Why this is happening ?

Comment: Because partialLength becomes 0.  Make sure it doesn't.  Could be as simple as `if (partialLength == 0) partialLength = 8;`

Comment: See my update, if numberOfFragments = 3 still endless loop

Comment: Time to start using a debugger, I'd say.

Comment: what the value numberOfFragments need to do ?